# auto scroll stopped working when I added an an hover

Tags: javascript

I have a page that auto scrolls - the function scroll() below worked just fine.
I needed to add an on-hover function - which should pause the scrolling, giving the user control over the scroll.

I added some code to stop scrolling on-hover.

```
<script>
    var theInterval;

    function startScroll() {
        theInterval = setInterval(scroll, 50);
    }

    function stopScroll() {
        clearInterval(theInterval);
    }

    $(function () {
        scroll();
        $('#scrollDiv').hover(function () {
            stopScroll();
        }, function () {
            startScroll();
        })
    });


    function scroll() {
        if (document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollTop < (document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollHeight - document.getElementById('scrollDiv').offsetHeight)) {
            -1
            document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollTop + 1
        }
        else { document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollTop = 0; }
    }

    setInterval(scroll, 50);
</script>
```

I expected that the extra functions would stop the scrolling when the user hovers over the content.

What happened was that the scrolling simply stopped

Answer (score 0):

You are dropping the interval pointer from your initial call to scroll.  `setInterval` returns an ID to the timer that is running the function at the specified cadence.

Your code is kicking off the scrolling on the last line, but not capturing this timer ID to clear -- so on 1st hover you clear a null pointer in `theInterval`, then on blur you're starting *another* timer calling scroll.

You probably notice that it gets faster because 2 logic paths are now adding 1px every 50 ms.

On the last line, you need to also set `theInterval` to keep track of that call, like:

`theInterval = setInterval(scroll, 50)`

That should fix it.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response ... I added modified the last line with theInterval = setInterval(scroll, 50) but it did not make any difference

Comment: I do not call onblur explicitly - so are you saying that onblur is called as soon as onhover is left?

Comment: on hover effectively binds to the underlying onfocus and onblur native DOM events.

Comment: oh, ok - thanks - but still does not help me get it working ... :-)